# Get Pandas DataFrame readable datatypes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to get into a list the data types of the columns in pandas dataframe.

I can see the types by doing the following:

```
>>> df.dtypes
Date     datetime64[ns]
Value           float64
dtype: object
```

But if i convert this to list, i see:

```
>>> df.dtypes.tolist()
[dtype('<M8[ns]'), dtype('float64')]
```

What i want is ideally a list like this: `['datetime', 'float']`

But i will settle for :  `['datetime64[ns]', 'float']`

Is there any easy way to do this without having to use df.types.to_string() and parsing?

Comment: What do you want to use that for?  The dtypes really are `datetime64[ns]` and `float64`.  Numpy datatypes are different from builtin datatimes like plain `float`, so you'd have to give more information about how you want to map between them.  You can get a nicer representation of the datetime type by using `str` on it to get `datetime64[ns]`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `dtype`s have a `name` property:

```
> [d.name for d in df.dtypes]
['datetime64[ns]', 'float64']
```

(I'm guessing you don't need help transforming `'datetime64[ns]'` to `'datetime64'`)